# Adding Subview Covers Up Navigation Bar in Navigation Controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, subview

I have a Navigation Controller that at times I need to present a subview for entering a password.  The issue is that when I do this, it covers up the navigation bar, making going back in the hierarchy impossible to do.  I use XIB for this, but it doesn't give me the option of resizing the UIView that adds on it.

```
if ([student isEqualToString:@"No"]) {
    [self.navigationController.view addSubview:password];
    [self.navigationController.view bringSubviewToFront:password];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are a few suggestions (assuming I understand your issue). Given that you are prompting for a password, I'm assuming you would want the user to either a) provide the password or b) cancel entering the password (not simply ignore it). If they do the latter, then the cancel button could be used to dismiss the password subview.

Suggestions:

1. Add a cancel button to your subview to dismiss the subview
2. Use a UIAlertView to present a modal dialog to capture the password with cancel button (see below)

   UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Password" message:@"Enter your password:" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"Ok", nil];
   alertView.alertViewStyle = UIAlertViewStyleLoginAndPasswordInput; // masks pwd text
3. If you're set on your current approach then define the subview similar to the following so that it is offset from the nav bar (or use constraints)

   UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 200, tableView.frame.size.width, 100)];

Answer (score 0):

It'd be helpful if you could provide a screenshot of what you're seeing and an image of the interface design you're trying to build.

The code above looks a little weird. Using `addSubview:` to add this type of view to your navigationController will likely have unintended consequences.

I would recommend either:

1. Building your password-entry UI in a new `UIViewController` subclass and using `pushViewController:animated:` to add this new viewController to the view hierarchy.

or

1. Use an alertView to capture the password entry, by either using the system `UIAlertView` or by building a custom alertView using a `UIWindow`.

Let me know if you need further explanation / clarification.